# sass compile error while trying sass --watch ./folder ./css

Tags: css, node.js, npm, webpack, sass

```
Unexpected exception:
NullError: method not found: 'length' on null


/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 8583:23   tF.eA
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 8585:28   tF.aB
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 8285:14   kX.bV
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 10318:36  <fn>
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 2912:71   DR.a
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 3147:23   DR.$2
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 3145:26   Ca.dart.Ca.$2  
         /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 4255:23   AV.ud
        /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 3391:51   dM.tn
        /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js 3633:7    Aq.$0
```

Can anyone help me with this?
I was using the command `sass --watch ./src/sass ./src/css` when this error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a colon `:` between src and destination `sass --watch ./src/sass:./src/css`